# Guzzlehttp\Exception\ConnectionException: cURL error 28 resolving timeout after 2851 milisecond

Tags: php, laravel-5, search-engine, guzzle, algolia

I have recently integrated Algolia with my laravel application using Laravel-Scout library. Whenever, I try to search to search any products using algolia, I get GuzzelHttp\Exception\Connection\Exception. Following is the screen output of the response. The same issue also appears when I sync my database with Algolia's server. I have doubled checked my Algolia credentials in my project and they match correctly. I am running this project in linux mint-18.04 LTS, using default laravel server (neither Apache nor Nginx) and MySQL server.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved in the following way, given that you have already added Scout to your project:

1. Create your own `app\Scout\EngineManager.php`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Scout;

use Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Config\SearchConfig;
use Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\SearchClient as Algolia;
use Algolia\AlgoliaSearch\Support\UserAgent;
use Laravel\Scout\EngineManager as BaseEngineManager;
use Laravel\Scout\Engines\AlgoliaEngine;

class EngineManager extends BaseEngineManager
{
    /**
     * Create an Algolia engine instance.
     *
     * @return \Laravel\Scout\Engines\AlgoliaEngine
     */
    public function createAlgoliaDriver()
    {
        $this->ensureAlgoliaClientIsInstalled();

        UserAgent::addCustomUserAgent('Laravel Scout', '7.0.0');

        $config = SearchConfig::create(config('scout.algolia.id'), config('scout.algolia.secret'));
        $config->setConnectTimeout(10);

        $algolia = Algolia::createWithConfig($config);

        return new AlgoliaEngine(
            $algolia,
            config('scout.soft_delete')
        );
    }
}
```

2. Create your own `app\Scout\Searchable.php`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Scout;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable as BaseSearchable;

trait Searchable
{
    use BaseSearchable;

    /**
     * Get the Scout engine for the model.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function searchableUsing()
    {
        return app(EngineManager::class)->engine();
    }
}
```

3. Create your own `app\Providers\ScoutServiceProvider.php`:

```php
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Scout\EngineManager;
use Laravel\Scout\ScoutServiceProvider as BaseScoutServiceProvider;

class ScoutServiceProvider extends BaseScoutServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton(EngineManager::class, function ($app) {
            return new EngineManager($app);
        });

        parent::register();
    }
}
```

4. Exclude the default scout package from the package discovery in your `composer.json`:

```
"extra": {
    "laravel": {
        "dont-discover": [
            "laravel/scout"
        ]
    }
},
```

5. Add your `ScoutServiceProvider` to the provider list in `config/app.php`.
6. Run `composer dumpautoload`.
7. Whenever adding the `Searchable` trait to a model, add your own trait to it instead of Scout's.

If you would like to make the timeout environment-dependent, it can be extracted to a config setting. Also please keep it in mind that the above is a bare minimum for getting the `Searchable` trait to work with a longer timeout, other classes may also need to be overridden for other features to work.

Comment: I will try this.

Comment: @TAM great, I'm curious how it goes.

Comment: Update: I tried your approach but it wasn't working either. I instead downgraded my Laravel Scout version from 2.0 to 1.27. Now it's working fine apparently.

Comment: @TAM That's interesting, I got it working without any issues using Laravel 5.8 and the latest Scout (7.1.2). You mentioned that you used Scout 2, that is a really old version, its code looked very different compared to the current one.

In order to be able to provide a working solution next time, could you please post the various libraries' versions in your question as well?

Thank you.

Comment: In the documentation, version 2.0 is mentioned for installation. I thought that this was the latest one. I didn't know that scout's version was source of problem. However, I'll mention relevant library versions next time.

Comment: It worked like a charm in my case. Thanks @SzaszaPalmer.

Answer (score 0):

Algolia has [default timeouts](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/configuring-timeouts/) and this error pops when requests are over the default (I believe 2 seconds). You can check how long requests might be taking for you with: `time host [ALGOLIA_ID].algolia.net`. Unfortunately, Laravel Scout doesn't have the ability to override this and I've not found a good workaround.